# Easiest way to extract 4 digit number out of string?

Tags: .net, regex

If I know a string is going to be something like:

`ABC XYZ 5678`

or

`QWEROI YREOIU 4679`

What is the best way to extract the last 4 digit string?

Answer (score 2):

In c# the whole thing would be

```
String myString = "QWEROI YREOIU 4679";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{4}$");
Match result = regex.Match(myString);
```

You can then use .ToString() if you need to keep working with the match. 
For additional information about regex i recommend [this article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

This would work `(\d{4})$` I guess.

To get the match using regex you could use this code

```
string input = "ABC XYZ 5678";
string regex = @"(\d{4})$";
string matchResult = Regex.Match(input, regex).Groups[1].Value;
int number = int.Parse(matchResult);
```

Or you could just use the following if the number is always 4 digits long and it is at the end of the string:

```
string input = "ABC XYZ 5678";
int number = int.Parse(input.Substring(input.Length-4));
```